# Exctract Month and Day to create a date

Tags: reporting-services, expression

I am trying to extract a numeric month and date from a give hire date to create an annual anniversary date in report builder.

Thus far I have tried the code below:

=Year(Now) +"-"+ Month(Fields!hire_date.Value) +"-"+ Day(Fields!hire_date.Value)

I got a #Error in the field I am trying to populate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like you're simply using the wrong syntax to concatenate the date.  Additionally, you could simplify the expression using `FORMAT`. Try this:

```
=Year(Now()) & "-" & Format(Fields!hire_date.Value, "MM-dd")
```

This should return the date in the format `2019-06-21`.

For other ways to format the date, see [this link.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32557.ssrs-date-time-expressions.aspx)